# How to create Code name one dynamic list using ui builder

Tags: codenameone

Can Any one post a sample dynamic list using U i builder in code name one without hard code.
i **want a list populated through dynamic data.?**

```
protected boolean initListModelList(List cmp) {

 cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(new String[] {"Firstname", "LastName", "Email"}));
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code populates CN1 Multilist dynamically from a Hashtable. Here usersList is a Hashtable. Write the code in the List Model event of the List.

```
    Vector vec = new Vector();

    Object[] keys = usersList.keySet().toArray();

    for (int iter = 0; iter < keys.length; iter++) {
        InputStream is = null;
        Hashtable temp = new Hashtable();
        temp.put("Line1", usersList.get(keys[iter]));
        vec.addElement(temp);
    }
    cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(vec));
    vec.clear();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem? Instead of using an array just pass a collection with your data or pretty much anything you want.

If you want to download data dynamically or something more elaborate just implement your own `ListModel` to fetch data asynchronously e.g. https://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/cloud/CloudListModel.java